# Как распарсить JSON с одинаковыми полями в Java?

Tags: java, json, gson

Есть следующий JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "interests":"hobbies.1",
      "age":"age.1",
      "gender":"gender.1"
   }
]
```

Если я хочу его распарсить с помощью GSON я делаю следующее:

```
List<Map<String, String>> newList= gson.fromJson(JSON, new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>()
```

Но что мне делать если имена полей совпадают? Map в таком случае не подходит

```
[  
   {  
      "interests":"hobbies.1",
      "interests":"hobbies.2",
      "gender":"gender.1"
   }
]
```

Comment: такого json в принципе не может быть. одинаковых ключей просто не сможет существовать в одной ступени иерархии

Comment: Зачем делать, чтобы имена полей совпадали? Не думали, сделать массив из элементов hobbies.1,  hobbies.2.И еще, во втором случае это не json, потому что вы не соблюдаете стандарт, а просто тип данных "Константин", придуманный вами и похожий на json

Comment: такой json никто не обязан парсить, он невалиден

Answer (score 4):

Стандарт не считает это ошибкой, но никаких гарантий не дает. Большинство библиотек либо превращают JSON-объект в пары ключ-значение и хранят в структурах, не предусматривающих повтор ключей, либо парсят в POJO-объекты, в которых по определению не может быть полей с одинаковыми именами.

> When the names within an object are not
> unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
> unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair
> only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the
> object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs,
> including duplicates.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6

В такой ситуации лучше всего договариваться с авторами этого JSON, чтобы они сделали поля уникальными. Попробуйте убедить их, что это ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, как советовали в соседнем ответе, нужно попробовать убедить авторов в том, что такой формат имеет некоторые недостатки. Если же такой возможности нет в силу разных причин, можно обойти эту ситуацию следующими способами:

#### Использовать JsonReader

Здесь всё просто -- императивно читается входной JSON-поток и, используя довольно запутанную логику, собирается единый результат.

#### Использовать `Multimap` и Google Guava и написать для него свой `TypeAdapter`

`Multimap` обладает множеством интересных особенностей и удобств, которые можно достичь и с использованием `Map<String, List<?>>` (но это, как говорится, на выбор, поскольку не всегда есть возможность использовать ту или иную библиотеку, но принцип останется прежним).

```java
final class MultimapTypeAdapter<V>
        extends TypeAdapter<Multimap<String, V>> {

    private final Gson gson;
    private final Type valueType;

    private MultimapTypeAdapter(final Gson gson, final Type valueType) {
        this.gson = gson;
        this.valueType = valueType;
    }

    static <V> TypeAdapter<Multimap<String, V>> getMultimapTypeAdapter(final Gson gson, final Type valueType) {
        return new MultimapTypeAdapter<>(gson, valueType);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Multimap<String, V> multimap)
            throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        for ( final Entry<String, V> e : multimap.entries() ) {
            final String key = e.getKey();
            final V value = e.getValue();
            out.name(key);
            gson.toJson(value, valueType, out);
        }
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Multimap<String, V> read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final Multimap<String, V> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        in.beginObject();
        while ( in.peek() != END_OBJECT ) {
            final String key = in.nextName();
            final V value = gson.fromJson(in, valueType);
            multimap.put(key, value);
        }
        in.endObject();
        return multimap;
    }

}
```

`JsonReader` использовать предпочтительней, потому как он не различает дубликаты, является потоковым и почти не хранит состояние. Если не ошибаюсь, другие адаптеры типов могут отслеживать дубликаты (вроде, `Map`-адаптер так делает). Поэтому без проблем можно собрать мультимапу. Дальше, теперь нужно зарегистрировать этот адаптер для любой реализации и параметризации `Multimap`:

```java
final class MultimapTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory multimapTypeAdapterFactory = new MultimapTypeAdapterFactory();

    private MultimapTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getMultimapTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return multimapTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( Multimap.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            final Type type = typeToken.getType();
            final Type valueType = type instanceof ParameterizedType
                    ? ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[1]
                    : Object.class;
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            final TypeAdapter<T> castActualTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter) getMultimapTypeAdapter(gson, valueType);
            return castActualTypeAdapter;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Код выше также не представляется сложным. Ну и в конце-концов можно попробовать как он работает:

```java
private static final TypeToken<List<Multimap<String, String>>> stringToStringMultimapListTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<Multimap<String, String>>>() {
};

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static final TypeToken<List<Multimap>> rawMultimapListTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<Multimap>>() {
};

private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getMultimapTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final List<Multimap<String, String>> parameterizedMultimaps = gson.fromJson(JSON, stringToStringMultimapListTypeToken.getType());
    out.println(parameterizedMultimaps);
    out.println(gson.toJson(parameterizedMultimaps, stringToStringMultimapListTypeToken.getType()));
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    final List<Multimap> rawMultimaps = gson.fromJson(JSON, rawMultimapListTypeToken.getType());
    out.println(rawMultimaps);
}
```

В итоге в stdout будет записано следующее:

> [{gender=[gender.1], interests=[hobbies.1, hobbies.2]}]
>   [{"gender":"gender.1","interests":"hobbies.1","interests":"hobbies.2"}]
>   [{gender=[gender.1], interests=[hobbies.1, hobbies.2]}]